# regex to add hypen in dates

Tags: regex, r

In R I have a character string that looks like the following

```
x <- c("20130603 00:00:03.102","20130703 00:01:03.103","20130804 00:03:03.104")
```

I would like to to look like the following by using a  single `gsub` command (rather than using `substr` and `paste`, but my limited `regex` knowledge is frustrating me in working out what i need to do to do so:

```
y <- gsub([REGEX PATTERN TO MATCH],[REPLACEMENT PATTERN TO INSERT HYPHEN] ,x)

> y
[1] "2013-06-03 00:00:03.102" "2013-07-03 00:01:03.103" "2013-08-04 00:03:03.104"
```

In my actual example, x has a length of several million, so any microbenchmarking for speed improvements would be helpful.

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
gsub("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "\\1-\\2-\\3", subject, perl=TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

i actually came up with the exact same thing as Tim. if you want something more compact try using the [stringr package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html://) with it.

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all("(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})", "$1-$2-$3")
```