# regex remove seconds and milliseconds

Tags: regex, r

This is linked the my previous question, [regex to add hypen in dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482929/regex-to-add-hypen-in-dates).

I would now like to be able to remove the seconds and milliseconds/change it to zero using gsub again as well

i.e. something like:

```
x <- c("20130603 00:00:03.102","20130703 00:01:03.103","20130804 00:03:03.104")


y <- gsub([REGEX PATTERN TO MATCH],[REPLACEMENT PATTERN TO INSERT HYPHEN and REMOVE SECONDS] ,x)

> y
[1] "2013-06-03 00:00:00" "2013-07-03 00:01:00" "2013-08-04 00:03:00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex, which I added a bit:

```
gsub("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*", "\\1-\\2-\\3 \\4:00", subject, perl=TRUE);
```

[demo on regex101](http://www.regex101.com/r/jL0nA3).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `strptime` to parse your objects into `POSIXlt` objects which, when printed, are exactly in the format you expect:

```
y <- strptime(x, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
# [1] "2013-06-03 00:00:03" "2013-07-03 00:01:03" "2013-08-04 00:03:03"
```

To remove seconds, use `trunc`:

```
y <- trunc(y, units = "mins")
# [1] "2013-06-03 00:00:00" "2013-07-03 00:01:00" "2013-08-04 00:03:00"
```

Having your objects as date/time objects will open a lot of doors, but if you really mean to store the output as a character vector, then just use `as.character`:

```
y <- as.character(y)
```

Comment: When doing several million rows, this is actually a bit slow...using `gsub` and then `fastPOSIXct` is a much more efficient method of doing things...

Answer (score 2):

A `lubridate` version:

```
library(lubridate)
dt <- ymd_hms(x)
dt2 <- update(dt, seconds = 0)
```