# Changing format of data in table

Tags: r, gsub

I have data called `payments` stored in table below that I took from a data base [Data taken from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4aku.png)

Now I only need to change the format of the `Week` column , so instead of it being (`201625`) to (`2016-25`). Only adding hyphen between to make it more clear that its a year and then week.
Of course I cant change the data from the database so I tried using

```
pdm_data [2] <- as.numeric(gsub("6","-",as.character(pdm_data[ ,2])))
```

but this only looks for an actual number to search, not creating space and then putting hyphen in that space

Please help I really appreciate it

Comment: are weeks 1-9 `20160x` or `2016x` ? I didn't download you data, try `gsub('(?<=^\\d{4})', '-', c('200001', '20001','201625'), perl = TRUE)`

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482929/regex-to-add-hypen-in-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `str_replace` from `stringr` package:

```
stringr::str_replace("201625", "(\\d{4})(\\d{2})", "\\1-\\2")
[1] "2016-25"
```

Comment: Well is there something that changes the whole column? the code above just changes on row in the column

Comment: `str_replace` is vectorized. So `pdm_data$Week <- stringr::str_replace(pdm_data$Week, "(\\d{4})(\\d{2})", "\\1-\\2")` should replace the whole column.